# Alignment of points [(1), (2) and (3)]

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I want to produce

1. (1) blablabla

   (2) blablabla

   (3) blablabla

I want to make (1), (2) and (3) are all on the same vertical line

How do I make it?

I tried  `\indent` command or some kind of white space command but I couldn't achieve the precise alignment...

Comment: Is the "1." in the first line "1. (1) blablabla" meant to be there, or is it a list formatting error?

Comment: Without an MWE it's difficult to give concrete suggestions. Please tell us how you generate the enumerated list at the moment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Greenonline To be there.

Comment: @karlkoeller  Oh, thanks! I didn't know there is any pre-determined convention regarding formatting... I' going to read that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

With `enumitem`, two simple `enumerate` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the inner `enumerate` to be adjacent to the outer, you can add `itemindent=*`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),itemindent=*]
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I suggest to add some negative `itemindent=-5pt` to the second enumerate list? In my point of view, the separation between outer and inner item label is too large. It's just a personal opinion ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's just a matter of taste... Anyway, I'll add it in the answer.

Comment: Yes, a matter of taste. Anyway, I +1 it before ;-)

Comment: @GuldamKwak You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)